# Ajax, unable to append data to specific "data" tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this for generating php buttons, and I want to append a specific data right after the button in the table that's right below.

This is my html

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
     <!-- -->
       <!-- Button -->
           <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
               <button data-dnipass="<?= $dni?>" class="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">Ver líneas</button>
              </div>
              </div>   
              <table class="table userInfo" data-formpost="<?= $dni?>"></table> <!-- This is were i want to append -->
             </td>
</tr>
```

Note that its located inside a for loop

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($usuarios); $i++){ }
```

And this is my Ajax/jQuery call

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".ver").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();    
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
                data: {
                dni: $(".ver").data("dnipass")
                },
                success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);                                   
                $(".userInfo").data("formpost").append(data);                                                               
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The alert works properly, but the append isn't targeting the specific table below each button

**EDIT**: after testing the first answer still not works, this is how I see my html on inspection.

After adding to my Ajax:

```
alert(data);                                                    
$(".userInfo").data("formpost", data);
```

--

```
<td colspan="2">
  <!-- -->
    <!-- Button -->
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <button data-dnipass="12345678B" class="ver" name="ver">Ver líneas</button>
                </div>
       </div>   
    <table class="table userInfo" data-formpost="12345678B"></table> 
 </td>
```

This is adminVerLineas.php

```
   <?php
     echo "<tr>
     <td style='color : white'>Número</td>
     <td style='color : white'> 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td style='color : white' >Minutos Gastados</td>
     <td style='color : white' >1 / 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td style='color : white' >Megas Gastados</td>
     <td style='color : white' >1 / 1</td>
     </tr>

 <tr>
 <td style='color : white' >Tarifa</td>
 <td style='color : white' >1</td>
 </tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you adding button dynamically?

Comment: @ChandraShekar yes their `data-dnipass="12345678B"` is dynamic, based on php data

Comment: You can add your js code(button click) in for loop ending.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert `data` into the `data-formpost` attribute you have to use `$(".userInfo").data("formpost", data)`

`$(".userInfo").data("formpost")` get the data from `data-formpost`
`$(".userInfo").data("formpost", data)` sets the data in `data-formpost`

if your data contains table html, then you have to use `$(this).closest("tr").find(".userInfo").append(data)`

Comment: What does your data looks like?

Comment: Its a simple `echo '<tr> <td> ...</td> <td> ...</td> </tr>'` . I can see it in the alert, but not being appended

Comment: @mouchin777 That changes a lot, you need to give this kind of information in your question. Look at the last line in my answer.

Comment: Not really solving it. And even if I change the data to a simple `echo "hello"` using the previous function, it wont append it anyway. I have edited the post with the curent data anyway

Comment: @it might be because of the php inside your file, but can't say for sure.